# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3' - Matillion

Tags: python, boto3, matillion

I've installed python3 and boto3, and i want to run my python script from Matillion but it complains about boto3 module not being available:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/interpreter-input-106f3f10-6834-4b31-bfca-ea489348086f.tmp", line 15, in <module>
    import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

[image]

Also, if i create simple test.py and execute it on server it will through the same error.
Package is under this location: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3`
and it has following permissions:

```
drwx------ 10 root root  210 Mar 10 06:21 boto3
drwx------  2 root root  133 Mar 10 06:21 boto3-1.21.16.dist-info
```

Any idea what could be an issue?

Comment: Check that the python interpreter Matillion uses has the site packages directory in its PATH

Answer (score 0):

As @Tzane commented, issue was related to paths.

The path where i had boto3 installed (`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3`) was not in python paths.
So, first uninstall boto3:

`pip uninstall boto3`

then install in on new location:

`pip install --target=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages boto3`

Comment: Do you know why you have to specify a path?  I've never once done that in my many years using Python. Is Python 3.6 not the version of Python that you are running?

Comment: If i would run print(sys.path) it wouldn't show me the path where boto3 was previously installed (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3), so that was causing the issue. Not sure if you noticed but old path has this local folder in it /usr/local/lib/... If you ask me why it installed on this location by default, i honestly don't know.

Comment: Whenever I've installed a Python version, it has been self-contained and it has kept track on its own of where the packages installed into it can be found.  I think that if you're needing to deal with your PATH and these extra args, you're doing something wrong.  If after you install a Python version, you use the`pip` that came with it to install modules into it, you shouldn't have to do any of this. I wonder if you aren't installing modules into one version of Python and then trying to use that module install from a different Python install. If you have something working, I guess you're good.

Comment: Using the same `python` binary that you're using to run `print(sys.path)`, run `python -m pip install boto3`.  That will install `boto3` into that version of python.  If you then still can't do `import boto3` with that version of python, something's super wacky.  If for some reason, you don't want to have to install `boto3` into that version of python, then I don't understand what you're trying to do and I expect that you're overcomplicating things.